# Grafana - memory usage regarding to allocated

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, grafana

I have cluster on GKE where the Prometheus stack chart installed, each node have a 4G memory total, I realized that about 3G is allocatable  and about 1G are reserved for (kube, system and eviction threshold) which is 25% for the first 4G where **"'Allocatable' on a Kubernetes node is defined as the amount of compute resources that are available for pods"** as per kubernetes and gcp documentation.

For now I need a way to monitor the memory usage for a node compared to the allocatable(3G) size not the total(4G) one.

I tried `sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes) by (node)` to get the total memory size for all running containers per node as mentioned in many articles and then I have to compare the output to the one with `kubectl top node` command, the values are totally
different from each other, however `sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{container="container_name",namespace="namespace_name"})` to check the validity of the metric I got the right value compared to `kubectl -n <namespace> top pod`

I don't know what is the right metrics should I go ahead with to give me the right value compared to the `kubectl top node` command, so I can get the total usage for all workloads which can be divided by the allocatable size *100 to return the memory usage percentage

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to accurately monitor memory usage on GKE nodes and want to obtain metrics that match the output of the kubectl top node command. The discrepancy you're facing between Prometheus metrics and kubectl commands could be due to various factors, including how the metrics are collected and presented.
For accurate memory usage comparison, you can try the following approach:

Use Prometheus Metrics: Since you mentioned that sum(container_memory_working_set_bytes{container="container_name",namespace="namespace_name"}) gives you accurate values, you can consider using this metric to monitor memory usage.

Consider System and Cache Memory: Remember that memory usage reported by Kubernetes includes not only the memory used by running containers but also the memory used by the OS and various system processes. This might explain the discrepancy between Prometheus metrics and kubectl commands.

Check Node Exporter Metrics: Node Exporter, which is part of the Prometheus ecosystem, collects a wide range of node-level metrics, including memory metrics. You can explore Node Exporter metrics to get a more comprehensive view of memory usage on your nodes.

Use 'container_memory_usage_bytes': Another metric you can consider is container_memory_usage_bytes, which reports the current memory usage of containers in bytes. This metric can be more accurate for calculating memory usage percentage.

Validate Metrics: To ensure accuracy, validate the metrics you're using against different sources. Compare the metrics from Prometheus with the Node Exporter metrics and kubectl top node output for consistency.

Consider Using Node Conditions: Kubernetes exposes node conditions such as OutOfMemory and MemoryPressure. Monitoring these conditions can also help you understand the memory status of nodes.

Remember that memory usage can be a complex metric due to factors like kernel memory, caching, and various system processes. It's essential to understand these intricacies when comparing metrics. The Prometheus documentation and GKE-specific documentation might provide further insights into selecting accurate memory metrics for monitoring.

Comment: Thank you for understanding and sharing your answer, unfortunately I tried all provided metrics but I can't reach to the target values or the accurate one,I realize that the way to fetch the right metrics have a lot intricacies, I got confused while trying to compare such metrics and consider cache memory, kernel, system, etc..  since no articles provide a full solution for this approach, I don't know if it's biting off more than one can chew, I believe that is very important to understand and to apply on your production environment.